# Adding an external link to wordpress menu

Tags: menus, navigation

I am currently using wordpress menu like this ...

```
$args=array('menu'=>'menu',
            'menu_class'=>'',
            'before'=>'<span>',
            'after'=>'</span>',
            'link_before'=>'',
            'link_after'=>''
            );

      wp_nav_menu($args);
```

But what if want is to add a specific link to a menu item. Other than a wordpress page. Say an external link. What do i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `_doing_it_wrong()`. When you call `wp_nav_menu()`, you should be referencing `theme_location`, **not** `menu`.

The way the custom navigation menu functionality is intended to work:

1. The **Theme** registers *locations* for navigation menus to appear, via `register_nav_menus( array( 'location_slug' => 'Location Name' )`.
2. Then the **Theme** instructs WordPress where to output those menus, via `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'location_slug' ) )`.
3. The **user** defines the *menu itself*, via the UI at `Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus`
4. Then the **user** *assigns* a *defined menu* to the Theme-registered *locations*, via that same UI.

So, by calling `menu` instead of `theme_location` in your `wp_nav_menu()` call, you prevent the **user** from assigning a menu to that location. Very likely what's happening is that the user hasn't **defined** a menu with the name you're calling via the `menu` argument, and so WordPress is simply falling back to the default `wp_page_menu()` output.

Once you correct this issue, then you can define a menu with whatever links in it that you want, and then *assign* that menu to the appropriate *location*.

Comment: @RevNoah [_doing_it_wrong()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_doing_it_wrong/) is a real function used to show deprecation warnings when WP_DEBUG is on. Doesn't look like it's called in this case though. Did you have other comments on the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Adding links to a menu is done from the Admin area. You will find the menu editor under Appearance -> Menus.

Additional instructions can be found on the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen#Custom_Links).